# Why googleapis node module is not found in heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a chatbot made using Node Js. It uses "googleapis". It works fine when I create a server from my laptop. But I uploaded files to github and used heroku as server. I get "Application Error" on the web address provided by heroku to access the app. How to fix it.

> WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730004+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800 2019-11-20T07:55:39.730026+00:00
>   app[web.1]: throw err; 2019-11-20T07:55:39.730028+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730030+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730032+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module
>   'googleapis' 2019-11-20T07:55:39.730034+00:00 app[web.1]: Require
>   stack: 2019-11-20T07:55:39.730036+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730045+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730047+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730050+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730052+00:00 app[web.1]: at require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730053+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.
>   (/app/app.js:23:16) 2019-11-20T07:55:39.730055+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730057+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730059+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730061+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730063+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10) {
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730065+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.730067+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
>   '/app/app.js' ] 2019-11-20T07:55:39.730069+00:00 app[web.1]: }
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.737402+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.737824+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.739094+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   messenger-get-started@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.739328+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.739554+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.739763+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
>   messenger-get-started@1.0.0 start script.
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.739994+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above. 2019-11-20T07:55:39.747500+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.747681+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log
>   of this run can be found in: 2019-11-20T07:55:39.747852+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   /app/.npm/_logs/2019-11-20T07_55_39_740Z-debug.log
>   2019-11-20T07:55:39.842413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2019-11-20T07:55:39.831194+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 1 2019-11-20T08:47:20.684024+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
>   path="/" host=mukupukuu.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=9bf7f838-97ee-4776-9517-b9c0b530241d fwd="49.244.16.204"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2019-11-20T08:47:32.344155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=mukupukuu.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=ace83680-39e1-489d-a50c-b1c6811f24ce fwd="49.244.16.204"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: did you include it in package.json dependencies

Comment: cool ,jsut gona add an answer for reference

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the GoogleApi npm package in the package.json This helps Heroku fetch and install the required dependencies on the server where your application is deployed.

You can add the package and version manually to `package.json`

OR

A better alternative is to run `npm install --save googleapis`